установка яндекса на linux ubuntu
только только начал познавать linux, возникла проблема с установкой яндекс браузера. скачал с официального сайта deb файл. пытаюсь установить через командную сроку по гайдам из интернета.
получаю вот такое собственно. вопрос, как фиксить и что с этим делать? файл сам в репозитории лежит.

там же написано, что есть зависимость, и надо её поставить. не?

Убери звёздочку и явно укажи один конкретный файл.

Ну или удали Yandex(1).deb

sudo apt install file-name.deb - так вроде бы автоматически подтягивает зависимости.

Да нет там никаких зависимостей. Автор просто случайно пытается поставить два одинаковых пакета потому что скачал его дважды, а в каком-то гайде написали звёздочку вместо явного указания имени файла.

Перевод ошибки говорит о том что была ошибка с зависимостями.
"Если же вы получите ошибку разрешения зависимостей выполните:
sudo apt install -f
Дальше просто повторите предыдущую команду sudo dpkg -i ~/Загрузки/yandex*.deb. После этого установка Yandex браузер будет завершена и вы сможете пользоваться этим новым браузером. Программа теперь может быть найдена в главном меню."
Цитирую с сайта https://losst.pro

-f   попытаться исправить систему, имеющую сломанные зависимости
